# How do I display only the connect status from netsh show interface command?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am brand new to batch and I am trying to isolate the connect status of my ethernet. Currently, I when I do the command

```
netsh interface show interface "Ethernet0"
```

and it is displaying:

```
Ethernet0
    Type:                 Dedicated
    Administrative state: Disabled
    Connect state:        Disconnected
```

I want to only isolate the connect state status, so I want the output to only be "Disconnected" in this situation. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: from `cmd` something like `for /f "tokens=3*" %i in ('netsh interface show interface "Ethernet0" ^| findstr /C:"Connect state"') do echo %i`. Double up `%` when run from `batch-file`

Comment: I suppose, if you were wanting to use this only on an English language system, you could pipe the results through `find.exe` matching the case insensitive string `connected`. You could make it more robust by using a `findstr.exe` regular expression, and look for ```Connect state:        Connected```, or ```Connect state:        Disconnected```. Once you have the appropriate line, to isolate the string `Connected` or `Disconnected`, you'd probably want to run the comnand within a `For /F` loop, and use appropriate tokens and delimiters, on the reurned command result.

Comment: Another way is `for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %g in ('%__APPDIR__%netsh.exe interface ip show interface "Ethernet0" ^|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /B "State"') do @echo %g`